# Dynamically adding component to a react page depending on state

Tags: reactjs

so I'm learning react via Udemy and the instructor wrote this code to dynamically render the content of the burger ingredients using the state. Basically, he is converting the state object to an array and using that to render stuff.

```
import React from "react";
import classes from "./Burger.css";
import BurgerIngredient from "./BurgerIngredients/BurgerIngr";

const burger = (props) => {
  const transformedIngr = Object.keys(props.ingredients).map((igKey) => {
    return [...Array(props.ingredients[igKey])].map((_, i) => {
      return <BurgerIngredient key={igKey + i} type={igKey} />;
    });
  });

  return (
    <div className={classes.Burger}>
      <BurgerIngredient type="bread-top" />
      {transformedIngr}
      <BurgerIngredient type="bread-bottom" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default burger;

//Object.entries(props.ingredients).map((indexOne, indexTwo)
```

The code seem to to very complex and I'm unable to understand it even after several times watching the same video. I mean, I researched online and saw that there is a better way to convert an object to array using

```
Object.entries(props.ingredients)
```

Can anyone explain me the existing code as well is is it possible to use **Object.entries** to make it any easier ? Or any other alternative method to do the same ?

**BurgerBuilder.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Aux from "../../hoc/aux";
import Burger from "../../components/Burger/Burger";

class BurgerBuilder extends Component {
  state = {
    ingredients: {
      meat: 1,
      salad: 2,
      cheese: 1,
      bacon: 1,
    },
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Aux>
        <Burger ingredients={this.state.ingredients} />
        <div>Controls</div>
      </Aux>
    );
  }
}
```

export default BurgerBuilder;

**BurgerIngriedent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Classes from "./original.css";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class BurgerIngredients extends Component {
  render() {
    let ingredient = null;

    switch (this.props.type) {
      case "bread-bottom":
        ingredient = <div className={Classes.BreadBottom}></div>;
        break;
      case "bread-top":
        ingredient = (
          <div className={Classes.BreadTop}>
            <div className={Classes.Seeds1}></div>;
            <div className={Classes.Seeds2}></div>;
          </div>
        );
        break;
      case "meat":
        ingredient = <div className={Classes.Meat}></div>;
        break;
      case "salad":
        ingredient = <div className={Classes.Salad}></div>;
        break;
      case "cheese":
        ingredient = <div className={Classes.Cheese}></div>;
        break;
      case "bacon":
        ingredient = <div className={Classes.Bacon}></div>;
        break;
      default:
        ingredient = null;
        break;
    }
    return ingredient;
  }
}

BurgerIngredients.propTypes = {
  type: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default BurgerIngredients;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anyone explain me the existing code

Let's start with this part:

```
Object.keys(props.ingredients)
```

This is used to turn the object into an array of keys. So it will be an array with `['meat', 'salad', 'cheese', 'bread']`.

Next up, it's going to map that array of strings to turn it into a different array. The function that decides what will be in that new array is this:

```
(igKey) => {
    return [...Array(props.ingredients[igKey])].map((_, i) => {
      return <BurgerIngredient key={igKey + i} type={igKey} />;
    });
  }
```

The first part of that to unpack is this, who's purpose is to create an array of the right length:

```
[...Array(props.ingredients[igKey])]
```

`props.ingredients[igKey]` is going to get the value associated with a given key. So if the key is `'meat'`, then `props.ingredients[igKey]` is `1`. Or if the key is `'salad'`, the value is `2`.

With that number in hand they next call `Array(1)` (for example). This creates an array of the right length. However, there's a problem. Due to a quirk in the way the array constructor works, if you try to call `.map` on this array, it won't work correctly (you won't be able to change the values). So to get around this, the next thing they're doing is making a copy of the array. That's what the `[...   ]` part does.

Now we have an array who's length is equal to the value in the object. The last thing to do is call map on that and create some components. That's what this code does:

```
.map((_, i) => {
  return <BurgerIngredient key={igKey + i} type={igKey} />;
});
```

When all this is done, we've got a 2 dimensional array. The outer array has one entry for each ingredient, and the inner arrays have components equal to the number for the ingredient.

> is is it possible to use Object.entries to make it any easier ?

I don't see that that would make any significant change. You could replace the use of `Object.keys(` with `Object.entries(` if you like, but it wouldn't change much else.

> Or any other alternative method to do the same ?

There's many ways this code could be written. Some are more readable than the example that was given, but they'll pretty much all have the same basic things they're trying to accomplish: Turn the object into an array, then for each element of the array create another array with the right length, then for each of those inner arrays, create a component.

Here's an example with explicit for loops, which i find more readable:

```
const transformedIngr = [];
for (let igKey in props.ingredients) {
  const components = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < props.ingredients[igKey]; i++) {
    components.push(<BurgerIngredient key={igKey + i} type={igKey} />);
  }
  transformedIngr.push(components);
}
```

Comment: This is a perfect example for when short code was chosen over readable code. `[...Array(props.ingredients[igKey])].map((_, i)` is just a hack to omit a for loop so he can stay functional and make everything a single command.